# Autoscaling Blue-Green ECS Clusters

Tags: autoscaling, amazon-ecs

I have a blue-green ECS cluster built in Terraform, based on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/bluegreen-deployments-with-amazon-ecs/. That article and the associated Github repo make no mention of autoscaling.

I'm trying to get Application Autoscaling working, but I'm not seeing my number of EC2 instances go up or down. Currently I'm using Target Tracking of ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization with a target value of 15. In other words, I want ECS to maintain an average CPU utilization of 15% on each EC2 instance in the cluster. If the average CPU utilization climbs, autoscaling should scale out to bring the average back down; if the CPU average drops, the cluster should scale in. (15% is too low, but I'm trying to exercise scaling more easily.)

Actual CPU utilization is above 50%, so scaling out is not happening. I suspect that the active (blue) and inactive (green) services are dueling with each other.

How do I get Autoscaling, Application or Classic, working with a Blue-Green cluster on ECS? I like the idea of Target Tracking but I'm open to other ideas.

Scaling Policies:

```
$ aws application-autoscaling describe-scaling-policies --service-namespace ecs \
    --policy-names hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking hub-prod_green_cpu_target_tracking
{
    "ScalingPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking",
            "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
            "ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue",
            "CreationTime": 1519243876.638,
            "PolicyARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:ORGID:scalingPolicy:db09a76b-f260-4699-b5aa-cb837086b87d:resource/ecs/service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue:policyName/hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking",
            "PolicyType": "TargetTrackingScaling",
            "TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
                "TargetValue": 15.0,
                "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
                    "PredefinedMetricType": "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
                },
                "ScaleOutCooldown": 300,
                "DisableScaleIn": false,
                "ScaleInCooldown": 300
            },
            "Alarms": [
                {
                    "AlarmName": "TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmHigh-768f842f-5811-4856-bccf-d73b91f20bfb",
                    "AlarmARN": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:ORGID:alarm:TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmHigh-768f842f-5811-4856-bccf-d73b91f20bfb"
                },
                {
                    "AlarmName": "TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmLow-d710adc7-5414-46a5-8222-fde9d816f4ee",
                    "AlarmARN": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:ORGID:alarm:TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmLow-d710adc7-5414-46a5-8222-fde9d816f4ee"
                }
            ],
            "ServiceNamespace": "ecs"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "hub-prod_green_cpu_target_tracking",
            "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
            "ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green",
            "CreationTime": 1519243876.577,
            "PolicyARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:ORGID:scalingPolicy:a407d322-c2a1-4363-9be9-1833f6d3dfce:resource/ecs/service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green:policyName/hub-prod_green_cpu_target_tracking",
            "PolicyType": "TargetTrackingScaling",
            "TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
                "TargetValue": 15.0,
                "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
                    "PredefinedMetricType": "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
                },
                "ScaleOutCooldown": 300,
                "DisableScaleIn": false,
                "ScaleInCooldown": 300
            },
            "Alarms": [
                {
                    "AlarmName": "TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green-AlarmHigh-d7a722a6-b7ab-4bad-846f-d728d4c03763",
                    "AlarmARN": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:ORGID:alarm:TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green-AlarmHigh-d7a722a6-b7ab-4bad-846f-d728d4c03763"
                },
                {
                    "AlarmName": "TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green-AlarmLow-074e9dde-7936-4b53-ba31-0665190c084f",
                    "AlarmARN": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:ORGID:alarm:TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green-AlarmLow-074e9dde-7936-4b53-ba31-0665190c084f"
                }
            ],
            "ServiceNamespace": "ecs"
        }
    ]
}
```

Scalable Targets:

```
$ aws application-autoscaling describe-scalable-targets --service-namespace ecs \
    --resource-ids service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green
{
    "ScalableTargets": [
        {
            "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
            "ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue",
            "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::ORGID:role/aws-service-role/ecs.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_ECSService",
            "CreationTime": 1519240496.0,
            "MinCapacity": 3,
            "ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
            "MaxCapacity": 30
        },
        {
            "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
            "ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green",
            "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::ORGID:role/aws-service-role/ecs.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_ECSService",
            "CreationTime": 1519167581.233,
            "MinCapacity": 3,
            "ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
            "MaxCapacity": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

Scaling Activities.
(1519252380 = 2018-02-22T2230Z, just before I modified the ALB Listener's default target group to Blue.)

Blue:

```
$ aws application-autoscaling describe-scaling-activities --service-namespace ecs \
    --resource-id service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue \
    | jq '.ScalingActivities | .[] | select(.StartTime >= 1519252380)'
{
"ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
"Description": "Setting desired count to 24.",
"ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue",
"ActivityId": "db73de6d-3918-4f24-94b7-de7437c767e4",
"StartTime": 1519252897.326,
"ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
"Cause": "monitor alarm TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmHigh-768f842f-5811-4856-bccf-d73b91f20bfb in state ALARM triggered policy hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking",
"StatusMessage": "Successfully set desired count to 24. Waiting for change to be fulfilled by ecs.",
"StatusCode": "InProgress"
}
{
"ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
"Description": "Setting desired count to 21.",
"ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue",
"ActivityId": "dce5efc9-2c93-4799-87bb-0d344a917de8",
"StartTime": 1519252837.315,
"ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
"EndTime": 1519252907.177,
"Cause": "monitor alarm TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmHigh-768f842f-5811-4856-bccf-d73b91f20bfb in state ALARM triggered policy hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking",
"StatusMessage": "Successfully set desired count to 21. Found it was later changed to 24.",
"StatusCode": "Overridden"
}
{
"ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
"Description": "Setting desired count to 18.",
"ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue",
"ActivityId": "e235d7c8-3558-4648-a276-5cb81f1b7af2",
"StartTime": 1519252777.465,
"ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
"EndTime": 1519252843.723,
"Cause": "monitor alarm TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmHigh-768f842f-5811-4856-bccf-d73b91f20bfb in state ALARM triggered policy hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking",
"StatusMessage": "Successfully set desired count to 18. Found it was later changed to 21.",
"StatusCode": "Overridden"
}
{
"ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
"Description": "Setting desired count to 13.",
"ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue",
"ActivityId": "47835aee-9c64-428d-81b3-0367da773370",
"StartTime": 1519252717.297,
"ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
"EndTime": 1519252784.681,
"Cause": "monitor alarm TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_blue-AlarmHigh-768f842f-5811-4856-bccf-d73b91f20bfb in state ALARM triggered policy hub-prod_blue_cpu_target_tracking",
"StatusMessage": "Successfully set desired count to 13. Found it was later changed to 18.",
"StatusCode": "Overridden"
}
```

Green:

```
$ aws application-autoscaling describe-scaling-activities --service-namespace ecs \
    --resource-id service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green \
    | jq '.ScalingActivities | .[] | select(.StartTime >= 1519252380)'
{
"ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
"Description": "Setting desired count to 3.",
"ResourceId": "service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green",
"ActivityId": "4b910f88-87da-4173-899e-246533c4d35c",
"StartTime": 1519253491.575,
"ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
"EndTime": 1519253558.285,
"Cause": "monitor alarm TargetTracking-service/hub-prod_ecs_cluster/hub-prod_es_green-AlarmLow-074e9dde-7936-4b53-ba31-0665190c084f in state ALARM triggered policy hub-prod_green_cpu_target_tracking",
"StatusMessage": "Successfully set desired count to 3. Change successfully fulfilled by ecs.",
"StatusCode": "Successful"
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you solved this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @A.Vishnoi, it's been so long that I don't even remember asking the question. My job disappeared a month later, as did the company, so I can't look.